# Webform submission token not displaying in confirmation

Tags: webform-civicrm, tokens

I have converted a simple create contact form from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9.

In the Drupal 7 form, the confirmation would display a button with a link to the newly created contact like so:

```
<p><strong><span style="font-family:Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif"><a href="/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=[submission:contact-id:2]" style="background:#792258; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 25px; color: #ffffff; border-radius: 4px; display:inline-block; ;text-underline-color:#ff3884">VIEW YOUR CONTACT</a></span></strong></p>
```

So for Drupal 7, I am using the `[submission:contact-id:2]` token to insert the contact ID and all is fine.

I cannot get this to work in Drupal 9? It just prints [webform_submission:contact-id:2].  Other tokens do seem to work (see below). It is not the old gotcha because it is in a fieldset, it's all one simple hierarchy of six fields.

```
[webform_submission:values:contact-id:2]
```

Will just print as typed above and not show the newly created ID in the confirmation message. I have found a work around  - add the contact ID field for the new contact to the form (it's hidden so OK), so using:

```
[webform_submission:values:civicrm_2_contact_1_contact_contact_id]
```

Works and outputs the correct newly created ID

This also works:

```
[webform_submission:contact-link:2]
```

outputs a full link to the new contact.

I am wondering if this is a bug to report or I'm missing some other integration or setting?

Answer (score 1):

OK - this has driven me crazy but it was entirely a PICNIC one (Problem in Chair, Not in Computer...)

This was the issue and it must have been an accidental click somehere along the line:

[image]

I do not know how it got checked on and it must have been me (!), but it was a real gotcha...  Unchecked and all tokens works...